# Proof of : Show that for Any Upper-Diagonal Matrix $A$ n $\times$ n with its diagonal coefficients equal to 0, $A^n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

- I want to show the following: For any square  matrix $A$ n $\times$ n of the form: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0 & a_{1,2} & . & . & . & a_{1,n} \\ 
  0 & 0 & a_{2,3} & . & . & a_{2,n} \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & . & .  & .\\
  . & . & . & . & . & . \\
  . & . & . & . & . & a_{n-1,n} \\
  . & . & . & . & . & 0  
  \end{pmatrix}$,

$A^n=0$

In order to do that, I want to show that if you multiply such a matrix b times. All the coefficients $(a)_{ij}$ such that $i<i+b-1$is equal to 0

- **My attempt**

I am trying to show that $\forall b, \leq n$ $(A^b)_{i,i+b-1}= 0$

I will try to show this by induction

- **basis** Let's show that $(A^2)_{i,i+1}=0$
  By definition, $(A^2)_{i,i+1} = \Sigma^n_{k=0}a_{i,k}a_{k,i+1}$

For $i \geq k$, $a_{i,k}=à \implies a_{i,k}a_{k,i+1} = 0$

For $i=k-1$, $i+1=k \implies i+1 \geq k \implies a_{k,i+1} = 0 \implies a_{i,k}a_{k,i+1} = 0$ And therefore, for $i < k, a_{i,k}a_{k,i+1}=0$

Therefore, $(A^2)_{i,i+}=0$

We now have a matrix of the form: $A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & a_{1,3} & . & . & a_{1,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{2,4} & . & a_{2,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & . & .  & .\\
. & . & . & . & . & a_{n,n-2} \\
. & . & . & . & . & 0 \\
. & . & . & . & . & 0  
\end{pmatrix}$

- **Inductive step** And here is where the struggle starts (I cannot finish this step).

Let $(A^b)_{i,i+b-1}$ be TRUE, let's show that it implies that $(A^{b+1})_{i,i+b}$ is TRUE:

$(A^b)_{i,i+b-1}=0$

$\implies$ $(A)_{i,i+b-1}(A^b)_{i,i+b-1}=0$

$\implies \Sigma^n_{k=0} a_{i,i+b-1}(a^b)_{i,i+b-1}= 0$.

**EDIT: I think I have solved my problem, can you guys confirm**

We now have a multiplication of the form: $A \times A^b =\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & a_{1,2} & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & a_{1,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & a_{2,3} & . & . & . & . & . & . & a_{2,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & . & .  & . & . & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & a_{n-1,n} \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \times  \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & . & 0 & a_{1,b+1} & a_{1,b+2} & . & . & . & a_{1,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & . & 0 & a_{2,b+2} & a_{2,b+3} & . & . & a_{2,n} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & . & .  & 0 & . & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & a_{n-b,n} \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 0 \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
0 & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

Let's call the first matrix $N$ and the second matrix $M$.

Let's show that $(NM)_{i,i+b} = 0$:

$(NM)_{i,i+b} = \Sigma_{k=0}^n n_{i,k}m_{k,i+b} = (0 \times \Sigma_{k=0}^i n_{k,i+b}) + (\Sigma_{k=n-i}^n a_{i,k} \times 0) = 0$

Therefore $(NM)_{i,i+b} = (AA^b)_{i,i+b} = (A^{b+1})_{i,i+b} = 0$

**I think I have succeeded to prove by induction that $(A^b)_{i,i+b-1} = 0$ But I am not certain**

Can someone confirm that my proof by induction is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is an upper triangular matrix, it's diagonal entries are its eigenvalues. However, all of the diagonal entries are zero thus all of its eigenvalues are zero as well. Hence the characteristic polynomial is:
$$p_A(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{(\lambda-\lambda_i)}=\lambda^n$$
But the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem states that any square matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial, and so $A^n=0$.

**EDIT** (Alternative Method)

Let $\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}, ..., \mathbf{e_n}$ be the standard basis on ${\mathbb{R}^n}$
Note that $A\mathbf{e_1}=0$ and that $A\mathbf{e_i}=0$ is simply a linear combination of the previous $i-1$ basis vectors for $i\in\{2,...,n\}$, and so it is now easy to show by induction on $i$ that $A^n\mathbf{e_i}=0$ for all $\mathbf{e_i}$and hence $A^n=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "satisfies its own polynomial"?

Comment: As in $p_A(A)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! That has answered my question. Do you perhaps know a way to complete the proof by induction (I am still curious to know how it can be done by induction)?

Comment: I've added an alternative method using induction above.

Comment: I have edited my post does my induction work?

Answer (score 0):

Show that in the 3rd power, the next diagonal from below will vanish. This is much easier to prove inductively. Then $A^n$ will have all diagonals zero, so zero all over.

Raising to successive powers sweeps up the matrix vanishing it down to zero.

Comment: Is it possible to complete my proof by induction without showing that in the third power?

Comment: Yes. Don't prove for rows only, also take into account that columns are also vanishing. Then simply multiply $(A^b)A$ to get your inductive step. You are multiplying a row of $A^b$ into a column of A. Up to some point (?), by your induction hypothesis, arrays on row of $A^b$ are zero. Show that after that point, now arrays on the column of A are zero. Thus the sum is zero.